# Spelling and etymology of "whatchamacallit"

Tags: etymology

> ...then he picked up this watchamacallit and...

I've heard the word *whatchamacallit* more than once, but never found it in a dictionary.  What is the right spelling, if it does exist? Is it acceptable in writing?  Is it derived from "what you *may* call it", or "What you *might* call it?"

Comment: [With](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whatchamacallit) [all](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/whatchamacallit) [due](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/whatchamacallit) [respect](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whatchamacallit), [try](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/whatchamacallit) [harder](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=whatchamacallit). :)

Comment: I think it's an interesting question! :) I learned from it.

Comment: @Susan I agree it's interesting. I'm just, howdyasay, teasing. Admittedly, from the Google results you'd think it originated with the [candy bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whatchamacallit_(candy)).

Comment: It's what's called a [nonce form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word), sort of a pronoun with a drape shape and a reet pleat. They occur in speech, and therefore have no official correct spellings. Spell'em like you hear'em.

Answer (score 6):

[whatchamacallit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whatchamacallit), also whatchamacallum: n. Something whose name has been forgotten or is not known. Synonyms: dohickey, doohickey, doodad, doover (Australia), doomaflatchy, gizwiz, thingamabob, thingumabob, thingummybob, thingamajig, thingo (Australia), thingummy, whatchamahoozie, whatnot, whatsit.

1928, compressed form of phrase "what you may call it." Earliest recorded variant is what-calle-ye-hym, attested from late [**15c.**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=whatchamacallit)!

Comment: ‘Doomaflatchy’?! Who on earth says that?

Comment: "I can't find your da** doomaflatchy; you're going to have to find it yourself!" I hear that all the time... (no, not really). Synonyms were [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatchamacallit) ;)

Comment: There are now 3 users of "Doomaflatchy".